# Creating a facebook application

Tags: api, facebook, rest, canvas

Hi I created a desktop application. I was wondering what I should put for my Canvas Callback URL. I tried to define it as local (http://localhost:8084) but it doesnt accept it.

I need it to get the session using http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&v=1.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your canvas callback URL has to be an address that Facebook can actually fetch data from. That is not `localhost`, since as the name implies *that is local to you*.

Read the following: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Canvas_Callback_URL#How_It_Works

> Your canvas page URL is http://apps.facebook.com/foobar/
>   Your canvas callback URL is http://www.foobar.com/yourapp/
>   [...etc]

Putting `localhost` as the canvas callback url is like buying something online and filling the shipping address as "my house".

---

For some basic information on how a Facebook application works, this is a good reading material:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Anatomy_of_a_Facebook_App

Comment: hmm but wouldnt that require me to own the domain foobar.com?

Comment: Do you have the application hosted on a server somewhere?

Comment: Well, you want to take care of that part first. Find a server, host your application there. Give Facebook your app's url, that will be the canvas callback url.

Comment: so i wouldnt be able to create a desktop application, it would need to be a web based app?

Comment: The application has to be web-enabled for it to be a Facebook app, yes.

Comment: And by the way, `foobar.com` is just used as an example here. You substitute it with whatever domain name your Facebook application is hosted at.